# DJANGO : Type Error 'an integer is required' AND Type Error 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am new to DJANGO and have limited experience in coding.

I am working through a DJANGO tutorial which involves building a cart.  I receive: a type error integer is required on the front end; and a type error bool object no callable in the admin portal when I attempt to manually create the cart.

I think the code is a little out of date from the tutorial, but my limited experience means any change I have attempted leads to further errors.

The code is as follows:
#TRACEBACK

```
Internal Server Error: /cart/cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\pharmamart\cart\views.py", line 13, in cart_home
    cart_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\pharmamart\cart\models.py", line 11, in new_or_get
    qs = self.getqueryset().filter(id=cart_id)
AttributeError: 'CartManager' object has no attribute 'getqueryset'
[27/Mar/2021 10:49:42] "GET /cart/cart/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71680
```

## settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store',
    'patients',
    'ckeditor',
    'cart',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pharmamart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / ''],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pharmamart.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ""
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = ""
```

#cart/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import cart

admin.site.register(cart)
```

## cart/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from store.models import product, customer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


#User = settings.AUTH_USER.MODEL# if included it throws an error 'settings not defined'
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.getqueryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count()==1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj-save()
            else:
                cart_obj = cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
                new_obj = True
                request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
            return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user = None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user is authenticated():
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "user", blank = True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('store.product')
    total = models.DecimalField(default = 0.0, max_digits = 50.00, decimal_places = 2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

## cart/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import cart

# Create your views here.
#def cart_create(user=None):
#   cart_obj = cart.objects.create(user = None)
#   print('New Cart created')
#   return cart_obj

def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

cart/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('cart/', views.cart_home, name='cart_home'),
]
```

Any help with amended code to show my errors is appreciated.

AC

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are expected to [show the complete traceback from the errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), and [make some effort to understand the error message and diagnose the problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). To help with the error from the admin portal, we would also have to see how you tried to use the admin portal, and not just the code.

Comment: I'm also unsure what you mean about getting the error "on the front end". Normally I understand that to mean that you tried to use the web page from a browser, and the web page didn't work properly, so you opened the web developer tools and saw that the Javascript code threw an error. It appears that you're only talking about Python code on the server, though, and the error you describe sounds like one that you get from Python.

Comment: Sorry first time posting.  The front of the webpage being /cart/cart/ gives error integer required and the localhost/admin/ gives error 'bool' object is not callable when manualy creating the cart

Comment: I have altered  cart/models.py from : ''' qs = self.getqueryset().filter(id=cart_id) '''  to read '''qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id =cart_id)'''.  The page localhost/cart/cart now loads.  However, the admin portal still does not load but now provides different error which has been posted separately.